# Conjugacy classes of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Studying the conjugacy classes of $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$ I understand any such matrix, we can have three possible representative $$\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(Q)$$ $$\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x-1)^2 $$  $$ \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x-1) \oplus \mathbb{F}[x]/(x-1)$$. Now when writing the rational canonical form corresponding to each representative, the answers my professor posted say that the matrix for the middle representative is $$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$ whereas I thought the matrix should be $$ \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$ since the companion matrix corresponding to the invariant factor $(x-1)^2$ is $x^2 - 2x + 1 \equiv x^2 +1 $. Can anyone explain why the first matrix is the correct one? Thanks so much for your help and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure what your "$Q$" is.  There are more than just three conjugacy classes, so I guess $Q$ is not supposed to represent any one particular polynomial.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention the $Q$ was supposed to represent some arbitrary polynomial with all roots distinct.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct by the usual definition of rational canonical form.  Your professor's matrix is a representative of the same conjugacy class, but it's not the rational canonical form (instead it is the lower triangular Jordan normal form).